# Error: [ng:areq] Argument is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I was attempting to make a simple app with Angular and I've stumbled upon

[image]

The error pops up when the page is loaded. What have I done wrong?

**views/raffle/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Raffler</h1>

<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
     {{entry.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**assets/javascript/raffle.js.coffee**

```
@RaffleCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.entries = [
    {name: "Larry"}
    {name: "Curly"}
    {name: "Moe"}
  ]
```

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>AngularTestProject</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is `RaffleCtrl` defined ?

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Looks like I forgot to define this. Can you provide an answer how to define this, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I am not aware of coffeescript. I will provide pure angular solution

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Don't pay attention to coffeescript. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <h1>Raffler</h1>

    <div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{entry.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller("RaffleCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.entries = [{
        name: "Larry"
    }, {
        name: "Curly"
    }, {
        name: "Moe"
    }];

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/jxxy85ax/)